# Need some help using print statement

Tags: python, printing, python-2.x

I tried this code:

```
x = 5
y = "Anshul"
print(x)
print('  ',y)
```

It gave the output:

```
5
(' ', 'Anshul')
```

But why the output isn't like this :

```
5
   Anshul
```

I added '`'` to get a space before my name, but it didn't work.
Is there any way to give space?

Comment: Try `print('\t',y)`

Comment: `print('  ',y)` can't produce `(' ', 'Anshul')`. You probably wrote: `print(('  ', y))`

Comment: @rdas is correct

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this myself. Are you sure you did the exact same steps?

Comment: Someone said to try : print('    '+y) to give space & solve the problem. It worked, that comment isn't showing now, maybe he deleted that comment. But thank you all.

Comment: It looks like you are using Python 2. To have Python 3 behaviour in Python 2, put  `from __future__ import print_function` at the beginning of the file.

Comment: @Matias Cicero I think it's because I was using this in python 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```py
print(' ' + y)
```

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is use string interpolation. 
See: [String Interpolation](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/string-interpolation)

Your code should look like this:

```
print('  %s' % y) # option 1
print('  {}'.format(y)) # option 2
```

Comment: It's completely new & informative for me, thank you Ray.

Answer (score -1):

Try using `format()`:

```
print('  {}'.format(y))
```